# Pagination of query results not work properly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pagination

I have a textbox in my PHP form where user can insert a movie title, an actor or director name (with jQuery auto-completion). Then, if user click a "search" button, a new window will be opened which shows list of movies containing the title that user has inserted in the textbox(or if user inserted an actor/director name, then this window will show list of movies by that actor/director).

### Problem:

Since sometimes list of movies are too long(for example, user may type only "wall" in the textbox and in this case number of results are 107), I would prefer to paginate results (showing 20 movies per page).

Here is the code for clicking "search" button:

```
$('#btnSearch').on('click', function (e) {           
           window.textbox = $('#q').val();
           window.searchType = $('input:radio[name=source]:checked').val();
           popupCenter("movielist.php","_blank","400","400");
  });
```

This is movielist.php:

```
<body>
<div id= "field">
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var searchType = parent.window.opener.searchType;
  var textbox = parent.window.opener.textbox;
  var pagenumber = $_GET['page'];

  $.ajax({
         url: 'searchfilm.php',
         datatype: "json",
         data:{q:textbox, t:searchType, page:pagenumber},
         success: function(response) {     
                     $("#field").html(response);
                   }
        });

</script>
</body>
```

and this is searchfilm.php code:

```
$searchText = (isset($_GET['q'])) ? $_GET['q'] : "";
$searchType = (isset($_GET['t'])) ? $_GET['t'] : ""; /* type of research */

 if($searchText !== ""){
  switch ($searchType) {

     case 'byTitle':

      $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

      $items_per_page = 20;
      $offset = 0;
      $page_count = 0;

      include('imdbConnection.php');
      $query1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT m.movieName, m.ImdbId, m.year, f.posterLink FROM featuredfilms_EN as m JOIN film_info as f ON m.ImdbId = f.ImdbId WHERE m.movieName LIKE :q");
      $query1->execute(array(':q' => '%' . $searchText . '%'));

      $row_count = $query1->rowCount();
      echo $row_count;
      if ($row_count === 0){
            echo '<td colspan="3">Sorry, there are no film matching your search</td>';
      }else{
           $page_count = (int)ceil($row_count / $items_per_page);
           echo $page_count;
           if($page > $page_count) { 
               $page = 1;    
           }
      }   

            $offset = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page;
          $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT m.movieName, m.ImdbId, m.year, f.posterLink FROM featuredfilms_EN as m JOIN film_info as f ON m.ImdbId = f.ImdbId WHERE m.movieName LIKE :q LIMIT " . $offset . "," . $items_per_page);
          $query->execute(array(':q' => '%' . $searchText . '%'));

             while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
         ?> 
              <tr>
               <td><img class='imdbImage' id="image" src='imdbImage.php?url=<?php echo $row['posterLink']; ?>' alt="" /></td>
               <td><label id='year'><?php echo $row['year']; ?> </label></td>
               <td><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/<?php echo urlencode($row['ImdbId']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>
              </tr>

         <?php
            endwhile;

          for ($i = 1; $i <= $page_count; $i++) {
             if ($i === $page) { // this is current page
                 echo "<strong>" . $i . "Page</strong>";
             } else {  
                echo '<a href="/movielist.php?page=' . $i . '">Page ' . $i . '</a><br>';
                }  
          }            

     break;



    case 'byActor' or 'byDirector':
      include('imdbConnection.php');
      $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT c.movieName, c.castName, c.ImdbId, f.year, f.posterLink FROM cast_movie as c JOIN film_info as f ON c.ImdbId = f.ImdbId WHERE c.castName = :q");
      $query->execute(array(':q' => $searchText ));
       //SAME AS BY TITLE CASE....
    break;           
  }
 }
  ?>
```

### My Question:

The result with my code is that it shows first 20 result(movies) in the new window,and also links to page2, page3, .., but when I click on page2, it again shows the same list of movies..(this is the same for other pages as well).

I know the problem is related to the ELSE part of my code in searchfilm.php where I put links to next pages. (I know there is no query after that to show the results), but even when I moved the lines related to query after else, then it shows all 107 movies in all pages (page1, page2, etc).

I really appreciate if someone kindly help me fix this problem,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you never set `$page` to the value passed in from the link, it's always set to 1 at the top of your `case` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your page variable to the php and add this to your code:

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1; /* page */
```

And also separate the pagination and the movie listing:

```
        echo 'Page ' . $i . '<br>';
        $offset = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page;
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT m.movieName, m.ImdbId, m.year, f.posterLink FROM featuredfilms_EN as m JOIN film_info as f ON m.ImdbId = f.ImdbId WHERE m.movieName LIKE :q LIMIT " . $offset . "," . $items_per_page);
        $query->execute(array(':q' => '%' . $searchText . '%'));
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
            ?> 
            <tr>
                <td><img class='imdbImage' id="image" src='imdbImage.php?url=<?php echo $row['posterLink']; ?>' alt="" /></td>
                <td><label id='year'><?php echo $row['year']; ?> </label></td>
                <td><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/<?php echo urlencode($row['ImdbId']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        endwhile;

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $page_count; $i++) {
            if ($i === $page) { // this is current page
                echo "<strong>" . $i . "Page</strong>";
            } else {  //I THINK THE PROBLEM IS THIS PART
                echo '<a href="/movielist.php?page=' . $i . '">Page ' . $i . '</a><br>';
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: thanks for your kind answer, but still I have the same problem.. I mean, it shows the first 20 movies and links to page2, page 3, .., when I click on page 2, the url is changed to http://localhost/movielist.php?page=2.. but the results are the same as first page :(

Comment: please kindly see my updated code in searchfilm.php.

Comment: But you do not pass the page parameter from your ajax: `data:{q:textbox, t:searchType},` It should be `data:{q:textbox, t:searchType, page: pagenumber},`

Comment: sorry if I ask very basic question, but where and how should I define pagenumber then? :|

Comment: where you define the textbox and searchtype in your javascript. when you creating a link, add a data-page="4" <-- page id here, and in jquery with `$(this).data('page);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I defined `$pagenumber = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code in `movielist.php`.

In your case, you send a GET request to `searchfilm.php` via AJAX, and any query string which passed to `movielist.php` will not passed to `searchfilm.php`.

So try this instead of your AJAX get code :

```
url: 'searchfilm.php?page=<?php echo intval($_GET["page"]);?>'
```

then, you can pass the `page` paramter to `searchfilm.php`.

Comment: Try to use "Developer tools" which can open by pressing "F12". switch to the "Network" tab, and then do page navigation. I'm pretty sure that your problem is passing your arguments from a page to another.